# Solr query with a facet range over 16 months returns the wrong value for NOW

Tags: solr, solr4, faceted-search

I have a Solr query:

```
q=*%3A*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.range.start=NOW-24MONTHS&facet.range=create_date_tdt&facet.range.end=NOW&facet.range.gap=%2B1MONTH
```

The only thing that changes in this query is the facet.range.start value, which would be either `NOW-12MONTHS`, `NOW-24MONTHS`, or `NOW-36MONTHS`.

For `NOW-12MONTHS`, the results set `"end": "2016-06-29T16:38:11.959Z"`

For `NOW-24MONTHS`, the results set `"end": "2016-07-28T16:15:17.087Z"`

These queries were ran minutes apart, so that end value shouldn't be for the following month.

I'm using Solr 4.8.1

Answer (score 0):

The usual good practices for date ranges is to ensure granularity is the same for the math. Which would mean bringing **NOW** to the monthly granularity with **NOW/MONTH**. You may need to adjust the end date to be slightly in a future to ensure you include today with new notation (e.g. end=NOW/MONTH+1MONTH).

I would test that and see if the problem goes away.

Additionally, having ungranulated NOW in the queries is very inefficient for caching, as queries cannot be reused.